# Improve PostgreSQL query response

Tags: postgresql

I have one table that includes about 100K rows and their growth and growth.
My query response has a bad response time and it affects my front-end user experience.

I want to ask for your help to improve my response time from the DB.
Today the PostgreSQL runs on my local machine, Macbook pro 13 2019 16 RAM and I5 Core.

I the future I will load this DB on a docker and run it on a Better server.
What can I do to improve it for now?

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dots
(
    dot_id INT,
    site_id INT,
    latitude float ( 6 ),
    longitude float ( 6 ),
    rsrp float ( 6 ),
    dist INT,
    project_id INT,
    dist_from_site INT,
    geom geometry,
    dist_from_ref INT,
    file_name VARCHAR
);
```

The `dot_id` resets after inserting the bulk of data and each for "file_name" column.

Table Dots:

[image: Table Dots]

The queries:

Query #1:

```
await db.query(
      `select MAX(rsrp) FROM dots where site_id=$1 and ${table}=$2 and project_id = $3 and file_name ilike $4`,
      [site_id, dist, project_id, filename]
    );
```

Time for response: 200ms

```
                                                                 QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=37159.88..37159.89 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=198.416..201.762 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=16165 read=16031
   ->  Gather  (cost=37159.66..37159.87 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=198.299..201.752 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=16165 read=16031
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=36159.66..36159.67 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=179.009..179.010 rows=1 loops=3)
               Buffers: shared hit=16165 read=16031
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on dots  (cost=0.00..36150.01 rows=3861 width=4) (actual time=122.889..178.817 rows=1088 loops=3)
                     Filter: (((file_name)::text ~~* 'BigFile'::text) AND (site_id = 42047) AND (dist_from_ref = 500) AND (project_id = 1))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 157073
                     Buffers: shared hit=16165 read=16031
 Planning Time: 0.290 ms
 Execution Time: 201.879 ms
(14 rows)
```

Query #2:

```
await db.query(
      `SELECT DISTINCT (${table}) FROM dots where site_id=$1 and project_id = $2 and file_name ilike $3 order by ${table}`,
      [site_id, project_id, filename]
    );
```

Time for response: 1100ms

```
                                                        QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=41322.12..41322.31 rows=77 width=4) (actual time=1176.071..1176.077 rows=66 loops=1)
   Sort Key: dist_from_ref
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 28kB
   Buffers: shared hit=16175 read=16021
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=41318.94..41319.71 rows=77 width=4) (actual time=1176.024..1176.042 rows=66 loops=1)
         Group Key: dist_from_ref
         Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 24kB
         Buffers: shared hit=16175 read=16021
         ->  Seq Scan on dots  (cost=0.00..40499.42 rows=327807 width=4) (actual time=0.423..1066.316 rows=326668 loops=1)
               Filter: (((file_name)::text ~~* 'BigFile'::text) AND (site_id = 42047) AND (project_id = 1))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 147813
               Buffers: shared hit=16175 read=16021
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=5 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 0.242 ms
 Execution Time: 1176.125 ms
(16 rows)
```

Query #3:

```
await db.query(
      `SELECT count(*) FROM dots WHERE site_id = $1 AND ${table} = $2 and project_id = $3 and file_name ilike $4`,
      [site_id, dist, project_id, filename]
    );
```

Time for response: 200ms

```
  QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=37159.88..37159.89 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=198.725..202.335 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=16160 read=16036
   ->  Gather  (cost=37159.66..37159.87 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=198.613..202.328 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=16160 read=16036
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=36159.66..36159.67 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=179.182..179.183 rows=1 loops=3)
               Buffers: shared hit=16160 read=16036
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on dots  (cost=0.00..36150.01 rows=3861 width=0) (actual time=119.340..179.020 rows=1088 loops=3)
                     Filter: (((file_name)::text ~~* 'BigFile'::text) AND (site_id = 42047) AND (dist_from_ref = 500) AND (project_id = 1))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 157073
                     Buffers: shared hit=16160 read=16036
 Planning Time: 0.109 ms
 Execution Time: 202.377 ms
(14 rows)
```

Tables do no have any indexes.

Comment: Could you please add the results (in plain text) from EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) _your_sql_ ; ? And did you create any index on this table?

Comment: Hope it's fine now, and thank you.

Comment: No index means you will always have a full table scan. And yes, that can be slow.

Comment: What index do you suggest to make?

Comment: At least site_id, because that's the one you always use. The other conditions might also be helpful. Check the query plan for the results https://explain.depesz.com/s/KwfN

Comment: I added an index and it helped a bit... ```create index idx1 on dots (site_id, project_id, file_name, dist_from_site,dist_from_ref);
```

Comment: OK. To give you better advice I need to know the cardinality of your columns, ie how many distinct values there are in each column your search on. So, can you run "SELECT count(DISTINCT site_id) FROM yourtable", also do it for project_id, dist_from_site, dist_from_ref and filename.

Comment: Also SELECT count(*) from the table to know the number of rows, and select pg_relation_size('dots') to know how big it is.

Comment: The amount of DISTINCT values is changing on daily basis. but is about 20-30 values.
the rows about 50k to search. and about 100K to the whole table but it's growing every day.

Comment: ```pg_relation_size 263749632 ```

Comment: So 5200 bytes/row, rows are pretty big, bitmap indexscan should work well. 20-30 distinct values for all searchable columns? Even filename? Trying to get an idea about selectivity. So when you search on site_id and project_id you expect about 50-100 rows right? (50000/30/30) And if you add a condition on one of the dist columns, maybe a few rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I added an index and it helped a bit... create index idx1 on dots (site_id, project_id, file_name, dist_from_site,dist_from_ref)

OK, that's a bit too much.

An index on columns (a,b) is useful for "where a=..." and also for "where a=... and b=..." but it is not really useful for "where b=...". Creating an index with many columns uses more disk space and is slower than with fewer columns, which is a waste if the extra columns in the index don't make your queries faster. Both dist_ columns in the index will probably not be used.

Indices are a compromise : if your table has small rows, like two integer columns, and you create an index on these two columns, then it will be as big as the table, so you better be sure you need it. But in your case, your rows are pretty large at around 5kB and the number of rows is small, so adding an index or several on small int columns costs very little overhead.

So, since you very often use WHERE conditions on both site_id and project_id you can create an index on site_id,project_id. This will also work for a WHERE condition on site_id alone. If you sometimes use project_id alone, you can swap the order of the columns so it appears first, or even create another index.

You say the cardinality of these columns is about 30, so selecting on one value of site_id or project_id should hit 1/30 or 3.3% of the table, and selecting on both columns should hit 0.1% of the table, if they are uncorrelated and evenly distributed. This should already result in a substantial speedup.

You could also add an index on dist_from_site, and another one on dist_on_ref, if they have good selectivity (ie, high cardinality in those columns). Postgres can combine indices with bitmap index scan. But, if say 50% of the rows in the table have the same value for dist_from_site, then an index will be useless for this value, due to not having enough selectivity.

You could also replace the previous 2-column index with 2 indices on site_id,project_id,dist_from_site and site_id,project_id,dist_from_ref. You can try it, see if it is worth the extra resources.

Also there's the filename column and ILIKE. ILIKE can't use an index, which means it's slow. One solution is to use an expression index

```
CREATE INDEX dots_filename ON dots( lower(file_name) );
```

and replace your where condition with:

```
lower(file_name) like lower($4)
```

This will use the index unless the parameter $4 starts with a "%". And if you never use the LIKE '%' wildcards, and you're just using ILIKE for case-insensitive comparison, then you can replace LIKE with the = operator. Basically lower(a) = lower(b) is a case-insensitive comparison.

Likewise you could replace the previous 2-column index with an index on site_id,project_id,lower(filename) if you often use these three together in the WHERE condition. But as said above, it won't optimize searches on filename alone.

Since your rows are huge, even adding 1 kB of index per row will only add 20% overhead to your table, so you can overdo it without too much trouble. So go ahead and experiment, you'll see what works best.